# How do I run Node.js code in a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working on a Wordpress plugin that let's an admin add a button that runs some Node.js code. I can't figure out how to run Node.js code through a plugin. Is there a good place to start?

Comment: The backend for WordPress is PHP, so you can't do that; an easy way is to use an API to run code and there are plugins to write your custom PHP code to connect with it. Here's an example of a freemium API: https://www.jdoodle.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can set up node development environment from this [guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/devenv/), and there's also a tutorial to create a [plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/wp-plugin/) with the [block editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/).